# pandas Series equality ignoring index

Tags: python, pandas

Indexes play a role in Series equality, I'd like to run a check that will ignore the indexes and just consider only values while also handling the case for different lengths.

`pandas.Series.equals` handles the different lengths part, but also imposes the index equality constraint. To get around it I'm doing the following...

```
def isEqualValues( s1 , s2 ) :
    return s1.reset_index(drop=True).equals( s2.reset_index(drop=True) )
```

So far this works well,

```
>>> import pandas
>>> s_a = pandas.Series([1,2,3])
>>> s_b = pandas.Series([1,2,3], index=[10,11,12] )
>>> s_c = pandas.Series([1,2])
>>>
>>> print( isEqualValues( s_a , s_b ) )
True
>>> print( s_a.equals( s_b ) )
False
>>> print( isEqualValues( s_a , s_c ) )
False
>>> print( s_a.equals( s_c ) )
False
```

Is there any official way to carry out this operation in pandas itself without resorting to a reset of index?

Comment: `np.all(s_a.values==s_c.values)`

Comment: @Wen: fails for `NaN`

Comment: @root yep , you are right :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with numeric data and want to handle NaNs, use `np.allclose`:

```
np.allclose(s_a, s_b, equal_nan=True)
```

- Works for ints and floats
- Handles floating inaccuracies gracefully
- Fine control over how NaNs are handled

If the length of the series being compared aren't the same, a `ValueError` is raised. To handle this as well, add a prelim length check:

```
len(s_a) == len(s_b) and np.allclose(s_a, s_b, equal_nan=True)
```

Comment: @root The question only hints at numeric data being compared though, but I get your point. If OP wants to cover every single case they should probably import assert_series_equal from pandas.testing and reset the index.

Comment: Yes, more of a note for future readers, as the question title is generic

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
(s_a.values == s_b.values).all()
```

Comment: fails for `NaN`